# How can I make the Tab selected stay selected after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

This is what I'm currently trying to do. Yes I want the page to reload after the form is submitted that is how I'm getting the "tab" variable to populate which is fine.

```
<!--- JQuery Tabs --->
<script type="text/javascript">
   <cfif (URL.tab) NEQ 0>
     var tab = "<cfoutput>#URL.tab#</cfoutput>";
   <cfelse>
     var tab = 0;
   </cfif>
    $(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    if (tab == 1){
           $( ".selector" ).tabs( "enable", 1 );
    }else if (tab == 2){
           $( ".selector" ).tabs( "enable", 2 );
    }else if (tab == 3){
          $( ".selector" ).tabs( "enable", 3 );
    }else if (tab == 4){
           $( ".selector" ).tabs( "enable", 4 );
    }else if (tab == 5){
          $( ".selector" ).tabs( "enable", 5 );
    }else if (tab == 0){
         $( ".selector" ).tabs( "enable", 1 );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: make use of cookies or local storage.

Comment: You can use a hidden field which will be populated on Tab Change and will be posted back and forth. You can use that hidden filed on `$(document).ready()` to enable the tab with the value in the hidden field

Comment: or put the selected tab in a URL parameter. BTW, why that `if/then/else` code instead of something like `$(".selector").tabs("enable", tab)`?